# Obtaining the mind maps and mapping them to the other language

Tags: vocabulary, comparison, pedagogy, understanding

Please tell me if I must separate my question but I see that one of the major language difficulties is that some words are sorta synonyms yet occasionally some synonyms have some flavours, which distinguishes them from other synonyms. [Mind maps expose the synonyms and sorta relation between words](https://www.google.ee/search?q=google%20translate%20vocabulary%20mind%20map)

[image]

You can travel through associations in different directions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Link to [source of the above diagrams](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/216673/mind-maps-for-increasing-vocabulary/blog/feed), and discussion thereof.)

---

My question is where do they get the mind map from? Who does produce/publish the map? How do I get my maps and how do I map foreign language map to my language or otherwise combine maps of two different languages? I guess there is no one-to-one correspondence between english, estonian and russian word map. Does the concept of mind map suggest that translation is evil? Should I learn new language as if it is my first language because and leave any attempt to find correspondence between two?

---

**Background**

This question stems from my attempt to build a google phrasebook. I see that some words are more like synonyms. I try to put them together, this helps me to highlight the difference between similar words. Since the list is linear, a group can be tied with two groups from above and below (I put a group between two others). This way I make a transition from one group to the other. For instance, `a hinderance-to impede-to resist-to oppose-opposite-to converse-conversation-dispute-a discussion` -- you see how can I can split this list roughly into 3 groups: impedance, opposition and disputing. But I can connect no more than two groups together since list is linear. This way, to overcome this limitation, mind maps come to mind naturally. I am interested to know if this approach is adopted and which tools can I use for graphical phrasebooking?

**Answer**

I have found the answer and give it here since my questions are claimed to have no definite answer, which is confirmed by blocking the answers. The map I am looking for is built by Princeton University, [project WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/)

> WordNet superficially resembles a thesaurus, in that it groups words
>   together based on their meanings. However, there are some important
>   distinctions. First, WordNet interlinks not just word forms—strings of
>   letters—but specific senses of words. As a result, words that are
>   found in close proximity to one another in the network are
>   semantically disambiguated. Second, WordNet labels the semantic
>   relations among words, whereas the groupings of words in a thesaurus
>   does not follow any explicit pattern other than meaning similarity.

You can browse through the thesaurus using online services like http://www.visuwords.com. It seems that the illustrations that I have posted were produced with [WordNet alternative, Visual Thesaurus application](http://www.eetimes.com/author.asp?section_id=14&doc_id=1283247). The fact that somebody builds one wordmap of all english words for everybody to use, grouping them by synonyms, confirms that the design is subjective and cannot be used/replicated by others. Thank you for putting this explicitly.

As of my another language words, how to match them with the synonyms of your primary language, I have realized that you can include foreign language into the diagrams as just another synonyms.

Comment: You'd have to ask the proprietors of whatever site you found those images on to find out who produced them and how they were generated; we can't answer those questions. The rest of your question is too broad to answer. Consider breaking it down to something simple and direct. But be warned that "is a mind map useful?" and similar questions will be considered opinion based.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName The rest can be another question. I guess that `how do you produce the map for a single language` can be one question, `how do you map different languages maps onto each other` can be the other. Why should I partition the second question into pieces? That is one question. Nowhere I ask whether Mind Map is useful or not. Where did you read that?

Comment: @Val This question is off-topic, but: there are varying methods for creating mind maps, and it will depend on the person making it - that is, there is universally-agreed method for creating mind maps, just as there are no universally-agreed meanings for words - you'll face the same problem with combining maps of different languages. I also don't understand how you think we can answer your question __Does the concept of mind map suggest that translation is evil?__ Your last question doesn't really make sense, and is far too broad to answer here.

Comment: You might be able to ask some questions on [linguistics.se], but translation requests and language learning advice is __off-topic__ there.

Comment: @jimsug Where can I see what is on-topic. Looking at the name, english *langauge learning*, I thought that this is appropirate (although too narrow -- general language congnition could be more appropriate indeed since the method is not limited to English and we could benefit much more without sacrificing anything. Can you migrate it there?). The question makes no sense in the context of trying to translate word-by-word.

Comment: You can check out the [help/on-topic] for on-topic and the [help/dont-ask] has a section for off-topic questions, too.

Comment: @jimsug I have scanned the categories and do not see mine in the off-topics. I see that it falls into "practical problems of learning English", on-topic.

Comment: _Translation and non-English languages_, _"How can I improve my English?" or "What's a good tool for...?"_, _"open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page"_, "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." It is up to the community to decide whether your question is off-topic or not; certainly, anyone can answer, and if no-one else thinks this question is off-topic, then it will remain open.

Comment: I don't think that this discussion is productive; other users will be able to make the decision. If you believe that your question is on-topic, then perhaps edit the question so that it appears to be so, rather than becoming defensive in comments.

Comment: My (final) closevote is for **Primarily Opinion-based**, rather than **Too Broad**. In the end, "mind maps" are just another way of grouping related usages around each "core" word, mapped onto a 2-d ***circular*** space. If we had the "representational technology" it might work better mapping around a 3-d ***spherical*** space (or 4-d, 5-d, etc., if we could get our heads around the concept). If the method works for some people that's fine, but 3rd-party resources will be limited (and probably idiosyncratic), so I wouldn't recommend it myself as a "primary" approach to language acquisition.

Comment: ...also I would just note that OP's examples as reproduced here wouldn't enable you to see a connection between, say, *giving someone a good **talking-to*** and ***telling them off*** *(reprimanding, lecturing, criticising)*. It's by no means a "magic bullet".

Comment: @FumbleFingers You should have some math background since you speak nonsense, that graph is a 2D structure, with such confidence. We should listen to you. Yet, enchancing this nonsense with 3d and n dimentions does not make sense either. Secondly, expressing your opinion does not mean that my question is opinion-based. I do not understand what your opinion and misdefining mind maps has to do with my question.

Comment: @Val - There are four or five preset reasons to close a question; Fumble is merely indicating which of those reasons best maps to why he has voted to close the question. Also, I think Fumble is right; we shouldn't read too much into these mind-maps. They are good approximations, and nothing more. Language is too intricate to map synonyms with precision – these are nothing more than a visualization tool.

Comment: @Val: "Mind maps" is just a meaningless buzzword. I may not be formally a "mathematician", but most of my working life has centred around designing information storage, retrieval, and presentation methods, so I'm perfectly well aware of how the diagrams you've reproduced here attempt to collate information. But they're inherently crude and liable to be subjective (why on earth would you map *William Tell*, but not *tell = count*, for example?) What about historical, syntactic, and other hypothetically mappable dimensions?

Comment: @FumbleFingers If mind diagrams are subjective the so are the dictionaries and textbooks. You should honor yourself for not recognizing that a Mind Map, regardless of the hype, is a invariably diagram. I wonder kind of person you are if you cannot realize that Mind Maps are graphs, that graphs are conceptual structures rather than 2D drawings and not being able to realize that even after somebody points this out for you. When I ask how to produce graphs I do not mind that you should have carrot in upper left corner and garlic in the upper middle. I as deeper - which words should I connect.

Comment: @Val: Even after making allowance for the fact that you're not communicating in your native language, I find your thinking confused and contradictory. Dictionaries (and thesauri) embody well-established techniques for linking "shared" information, which is why we use them *as source material* when learning. "Mind maps" are more commonly used in ephemeral contexts ("brainstorming" sessions at work, for example). They help you *organise your thoughts* - normally, prior to presenting them in a more traditional "linear" format, rather than as a teaching aid for use by others.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Mind maps represent things in their natural form. In the real world, things are connected with many others. Mind Maps shows how things are connected. This means that Mind maps are more revealing. It is stupid to limit effective communication for yourself and serialize for the others. The fact that you can draw quick-and-dirty relationships during brainstorms, which results in many errors. I do not see why you cannot represent your more elaborated diagrams to the others. I do not see any insonsistency with my previous statements.

Comment: If anyone is interested, I've reposted parts of this question on [Linguistics.se](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/8341/production-of-mind-maps). That being said, I'm not as sure of what is considered on-topic there, so we'll see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I've never researched this, but I would be very surprised if you found that words in English that have multiple unrelated definitions -- like "trunk" the nose of an elephant versus "trunk" a large suitcase versus "trunk" the main branch of a tree -- have the SAME multiple unrelated definitions in another language.

Even related definitions -- like "talk" a verb meaning to speak and "talk" a noun meaning a formal lecture -- I'd wonder about. I'm sure a linguist somewhere along the line has studied that question. Are such related definitions "natural" and so many different languages have the same relationships? Or are they specific to the thought processes of the people who invented one language?

I'm not sure what you mean by, "Does the concept of mind map suggest that translation is evil?" Do you mean "evil" literally here, as in, offends moral principles and violates the laws of God? Umm, I'd say "no". I'm guessing you mean, "Does this make translation difficult?"

Years ago I read an article by someone who had been involved in writing a computer program to translate between languages. He said that when his team started out, they thought this was an easy problem: If you want to translate, say, English to Spanish, you just look up the Spanish word for each English word, then re-arrange the word order a little to conform to the conventions of Spanish, and you're done.

They found that the results were totally unsatisfactory. In practice the problem is much more difficult, and one of the many reasons is that you can't always make a simple one-to-one correspondence between words in different languages. Words have shades of meaning and connotations that are not always reflected in a dictionary definition.

Answer (score 0):

Many English words have more than one meaning. Consider the word *pin*, for example. It can function as a noun or a verb; the word can be used in the context of sewing, wrestling, bowling, golf, or chess.

As for the word *talk*, there are three main ways that word can be used (this is a bit oversimplified, but it will illustrate my point):

- as a verb, meaning to speak
- as a noun, meaning a lecture
- as a verb, meaning to "spill the beans"

Once that is established, it wouldn't be too hard to put synonyms into specific groups.

As for how the maps are generated, I don't know for sure, but I imagine a program could look at the various candidates, and see which ones have common synonyms. That information could be used in an algorithm easily enough, especially after some programmers acquired some linguistics expertise, or vice-versa.

There is nothing ***evil*** about synonyms, but they are ***tricky***. In other words, they are hard to ***pin down*** ([Meaning 2](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/pin-down), of course).

Comment: Interesting, this suggests that corresponding words of another language can treated as simple synonyms, placed into one class with English words.

Comment: @Val - Not exactly. It means some synonyms can be used as synonyms, and some can't. It depends on context. My favorite example is: What is the opposite of _light_? Answer: That depends. The answer could be _dark_, or it could be _heavy_ – yet _heavy_ and _dark_ are not synonyms, even though they are both antonyms of the same word. If anything, it shows you need to be careful when doing word-for-word translations, because the translated word might be the wrong word.

Comment: What you are talking about is known as homophony. In your case, word 'light' would appear in different places of your map. Combining different languages, we won't have such problem. We will have the same meaning but different words. The same word in different languages can be considered as synonyms. I therefore think that `salty` vs. `sour` vs. `bitter` are all antonyms to a single word `sweet`. It is stronger example because it demonstrates that even single meaning of word, `sweet`, can produce multiple antonyms, depending on the axis that you are asking. But we have digressed.

Comment: I've [posted on meta](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/why-was-the-question-about-mind-maps-reopened) about this question.